# Did Michael Bloomberg ask for a box to stand on during debates?

Tags: united-states, politics, michael-bloomberg

In an [interview with Sean Hannity](https://edition.cnn.com/videos/media/2020/02/02/trump-bloomberg-box-comment-sean-hannity-fox-news-rs-vpx.cnn), President Trump made a claim about [Michael Bloomberg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michael_Bloomberg):

> You know now he wants a box for the debates, to stand on.

the implication being that he wanted to make himself appear taller  during the [2020 Democratic Party presidential debates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020_Democratic_Party_presidential_debates).

Is it true that Bloomberg asked for a box?

Comment: When Trump says "now he wants a box for the debates," he could mean that Bloomberg simply wants to participate in the debates (while simultaneously taking a jab at Bloomberg's height). I don't think Bloomberg ever publicly asked for a literal box behind his podium.

Comment: It's actually pretty common that candidates ask to be raised to the same height as others in a debate like this. [Dukakis asked for it and got it in the debates again George H W Bush in 1988](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2016/09/19/the-state-of-the-presidential-debate). [Castro did it in the Democratic primaries](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/castro-stands-on-box-to-look-taller-in-democratic-debate). To be fair, if the podiums are the same height (and they are) it's not an unreasonable request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no evidence of such asking.  And the campaign has flatly confirmed that [it won't so ask](https://www.washingtonexaminer.com/news/campaign-confirms-bloomberg-will-not-stand-on-box-during-democratic-debate).

It seems Bloomberg used a box, or some sort of [podium enhancement](https://freebeacon.com/politics/busted-bloomberg-used-box-to-boost-height-as-nyc-mayor-investigation-finds/) during his mayoralty and his inauguration.

[image]